# What's the difference between String and ::String?

Tags: ruby

I know `::` allows us to access items in modules, or class-level items in classes, but what does only `::String` mean??

What is the difference between `String =="hi".class` and `::String=="hi".class`??

The class is defined as below.

class String

end

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`::String` references the top level `String` class. `String` references either a string in the current namespace or namespaces above.

Take a look at the following code:

```
module MyModule
  class String
    def initialize(s); end

    def split(operator=nil)
      puts "This string doesn't split"
    end
  end

  class SomeClass
    def bar
       s = String.new("foo:bar")
       s.split(":")
    end

    def foo
       s = ::String.new("foo:bar")
       s.split(":")
    end
  end  

end

sc = MyModule::SomeClass.new

sc.foo
=> ["foo", "bar"]

sc.bar
This string doesn't split
=> nil
```

Since `String` exists in both the top level namespace and in the module `MyModule`, you need to explicitly reference the top level string by using the top level namespace `::`.

Answer (score 5):

In the specific case of `String` vs `::String`, the answer is: there will approximately *never* be a difference.

In the general case of constant `X` vs `::X`, sure. `X` might be `A::B::C::X` or `A::B::X` or just `X`, but `::X` is always "just `X`", whereas plain "`X`" could be any of them.

`String` is quite important, though, so no one will redefine it accidentally. In the unlikely case that an inner class or module named `String` is defined, it is most likely the intention that contained code use it rather than `String`, err, sorry, `::String`.

*Update:* I should add that simply seeing `class String; end` does not define class `String` in the sense that I think you mean. In Ruby, classes can be reopened. The `class` keyword may or may not introduce a new class. It might just be adding behavior to an existing one, and if there is nothing inside, then it's just a no-op. The old class behavior is still there,

Answer (score 2):

This means "access String constant from top level namespace".

Class String might be defined in some module - this will tell the interpreter to access the class in top level namespace.